# displaying exact data in ms-excel from asp.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have created an asp.net website,which stores data into an ms-excel sheet from the webpage,the problem is,all other column values except the first column(register number)are correct.when we open the sheet it displays a value "2.11511E+11" in the register number column.Why so? Im new to using ms-excel,pls help. And the datatype i used for register number is "long".

Answer (score 1):

This is just the format of the cell (represention)

Look at this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Date-Formats-in-Microsoft-Excel) to change represention